# stepwise for Ridge Regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I am doing modeling based on ridge regression by R.
I want to make a step-wise for ridge regression, 
however, i can only get a error which said

"Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute"

My R code:

```
TempReg = step(lm.ridge(DepVar ~ ., data = RandomVars,lambda = 0),direction="both", trace=0)
```

My R code when i use general regression (workable):

```
TempReg = step(lm(DepVar ~ ., data = RandomVars), direction="both", trace=0)
```

what can i do if i want to make stepwise for ridge

Comment: step-wise does not make much sense for ridge regression. Change the lambda to do regularization - provide a vector of values. If you are interested in regularization + model selection check out lasso. What ever you are interested in check out [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html)

Comment: Thank you@missuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try maybe using step-wise first and then ridge regression. But as mentioned, it does not make sense as it is basically Lasso regression. You could also try elastic net regression as it uses both the L1 and L2 penalties.

Comment: hi, @deez. I have picked up lasso instead of ridge with step-wise.how do you think about that.

Comment: I'm not too sure as Lasso gives a zero coefficient and removes the variables that it thinks is not relevant to the response variable. Step-wise does a similar thing. You should try them separately and see what variables have been removed from both. Compare these models and yours and they should be very similar. They may give you the same answer. Let me know how it goes